# How to properly use Properties.Settings.Default.Save()?

Tags: c#, winforms, application-settings

I'm writing an application with Windows Forms, .NET 4.6, using a bunch of settings configurable in run-time. Modifying, adding and deleting settings works fine within one run, but all changes are lost when the app closes. I do use Properties.Settings.Default.Save() just before the main window closes:

```
    private void TestersList_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

A user.config file is created as expected in AppData, but only one of the settings is saved there, no matter what I do with it or any other setting in run time.

All of the settings are defined in user scope and serialized as strings. I see nothing that makes the one that is saved any different from the others.
Below is a part of app.config:

```
<userSettings>
<DailyChecklist.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="SerialPattern2" serializeAs="String">
    <value>\d{10}_0_None</value>
  </setting>
  </setting>
  <setting name="SerialPatternDebug" serializeAs="String">
    <value>123456789</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="TestersToIgnore" serializeAs="String">
    <value>dummy;</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="SerialPatternDefault" serializeAs="String">
    <value>\D\d]{3}\D{2,3}\d{4}\d{5}</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="ServerAdress" serializeAs="String">
    <value>address/goes/here</value>
  </setting>
</DailyChecklist.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

And after saving I got this in user.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<userSettings>
    <DailyChecklist.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="TestersToIgnore" serializeAs="String">
            <value>dummy;</value>
        </setting>
    </DailyChecklist.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
</configuration>
```

How can I make it save all settings in user.config?

Thanks in advance!

PS. I have checked that it's not the scope, I have no '*' in assembly info and the file I was monitoring is the only file created (no version/build number changes). It gets modified (according to notepad++) and if I change TestersToIgnore, its new value is saved, but all other settings are missing.

Comment: Project > Properties > Settings tab.  Pay attention to the "Scope" column.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your comment, but as I wrote in the question, all settings are in user scope. I have nothing in Application scope.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out finally, so I'm leaving it here for future unfortunate souls.
The magical word is: `foreach`.

Although it is possible to iterate through `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties` in a `foreach` loop, changes are temporary. I mean solution like:

```
        foreach(SettingsProperty setting in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
        {
            if(setting.Name.Contains("someKeyWord"))
                Properties.Settings.Default[setting.Name] = someNewSettingValue;
        }
```

seems to be working within current run, but changes are lost after restart. `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` for some reason won't save anything that was changed from within a loop.

I checked and `Properties.Settings.Default[setting.Name] = someNewSettingValue;` works just fine outside of a loop and is normally saved then.

If you need dynamically added settings, consider using a single setting configured as one of `System.Collections.Specialized` types. It might make your code less transparent, but at least it handles loops well.

Comment: 'Properties.Settings.Default.Save() **for some reason** won't save anything that was changed from within a loop.' for what reason?